# Where are subdomains ("shortcuts") defined in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

On a corporate website managed with TYPO3 there are shortcuts defined which lead to a page on the site.

Example: 
Corporate website is **www.acompany.com**

Then there is a site **www.acompany.com/coolproduct** which is redirecting the user to **www.acompany.com/products/productgroup3/product25.htm** for example.

Where in TYPO3 can such "shortcut" links be defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably some page in the page tree has set type to: `Shortcut` which causes that it points some other page  or resource, it's also possible that is set as `Link to External URL` and there is full URL given.

Check the page tree in the backend and find your `coolproduct` page in it. Then check the site's properties and change if required to other value/type.

It's also possible that this URL is generated by some plugin or TypoScript, but in this case you'll need to investigate it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your help! What search term could I use to find the shortcut in the backend? "coolproduct" alone is a very common term which is used on many many pages. Is there a way to search for the link "www.acompany.com/coolproduct"? (if I just enter it in the search box, I get zero helpful results, just some pages where the link is used)

Comment: I currently found that the link `www.acompany.com/coolproduct` seems to be multiply defined, as it points to different pages... If I'm clicking on a banner on the start page, it goes to the wrong page (and displays in the address bar `www.acompany.com/coolproduct`, however if I enter `www.acompany.com/coolproduct`directly in a new firefox tab, it brings me to the correct page...

Comment: Apparently banner has some other url defined OR it has for an example link in the `ActionScript` (if it's a Flash animation), or something else... Use a firebug (or other dev tools) for investigate browsers request after clicking the banner

Comment: thank you very much! I think the Web-admin (currently on holiday) will have to do that. I was hoping for a simple solution, but it seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to find these kinds of things is actually using the search engine in the TYPO3 backend. You will find it in the upper right corner.

If this fails, what I do is install PhpMyAdmin from the extension repository. Once you have PhpMyAdmin you can use it's search functionality to find anything in the database using a search query of: '%coolproduct%' and selecting all tables. In the results look for the 'pid' field. It tells you on which page in TYPO3 the found item is located.

Answer (score 0):

Does the page use the extension realURL? If so, there might be realURL redirects defined.

Have a look at page -> info -> RealUrl -> Redirects

Comment: This would be also be my first guess and after that a .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you the user has defined this link redirection in many pages, you can search for it in the database exactly in the tt_content table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set shortcut for your domain to any page of your site, so when user enter only your domain name in url then it redirects to page which you set in shortcut.

For that edit your domain and set shortcut to any page of your page tree.